# Возможно ли динамически менять видимость папки?

Tags: android, файлы, privacy

Добрый день.
Интересует, есть ли способ открыть для Галереи фотографии, если файл к ним создаётся следующим кодом.

```
File photoFile = new File(context.getDir(mPhotoPath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE), name + "." + type);
```

Ключевой пункт моего вопроса - Context.MODE_PRIVATE. Есть ли какая-то возможность динамически во время работы приложения открывать/скрывать папку?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам [это](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setReadable(boolean)) поможет(если еще не найдено было ранее). Работает на андроид 2.3 и выше

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но заказчик решил логику поменять.